# Bottom Navigation Bar with ViewPager vs Navgraph

Tags: kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-viewpager2

I am working on Bottom Navigation bar using fragment. What is the difference if we use bottom navigation bar with View Pager or Nav Graph?

Answer (score 2):

il explain in a very easy way to understand

Nav graph is way for developer to connect fragments, before this way wasnt available in android, we used to be able to do only through code, think of nav graph as a enlarged google maps preview of your city. Below screenshot

[image]

Bottom navigation (highlighted in orange)is a navigation between your fragments

View Pager(highlighted in red) is a way to have to different parts in one fragment, for example in my news fragment i have crypto news and saved news.

[image]

here googles tutorial on it if your wanna have a deeper look https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started